# unity5.2.4 build ios package Error

Tags: unity-game-engine

Have problem when build ios package.

Here is the log

The log is build in windows (unity5.2.2f1).

And the same error in macOs (unity 5.2.4f1)

> Error1: Failed running D:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\Tools/UnusedByteCodeStripper2/UnusedBytecodeStripper2.exe -out "F:\client1\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\tempStrip" -l none -c link -x "D:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\Tools\native_link.xml" -f "D:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\il2cpp\LinkerDescriptors" -x "F:\client1\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed..\platform_native_link.xml" -x "F:\client1/Temp/StagingArea/Data/methods_pointedto_by_uievents.xml" -x "F:\client1\Assets\Scripts\AStarScript\link.xml" -d "F:\client1\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed" -a "F:\client1\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp-firstpass.dll" -a "F:\client1\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Assembly-CSharp.dll" -a "F:\client1\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Assembly-UnityScript-firstpass.dll" -a "F:\client1\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\Assembly-UnityScript.dll" -a "F:\client1\Temp\StagingArea\Data\Managed\UnityEngine.UI.dll"
>
> stdout:
>    SweepReport:
>    System.MonoType => Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinitionMono.Cecil.TypeDefinitionMono.Cecil.TypeDefinitionMono.Cecil.TypeDefinitionMono.Cecil.TypeDefinition
>    Mono.Cecil.MethodDefinition => System.Boolean System.EnterpriseServices.IConfigurationAttribute.AfterSaveChanges(System.Collections.Hashtable)System.Boolean System.EnterpriseServices.IConfigurationAttribute.Apply(System.Collections.Hashtable)System.Boolean System.EnterpriseServices.IConfigurationAttribute.IsValidTarget(System.String)System.Guid get_Value()System.Boolean System.EnterpriseServices.IConfigurationAttribute.AfterSaveChanges(System.Collections.Hashtable)
>    Mono.Cecil.FieldDefinition => System.String LiteralFalseSystem.String LiteralTrueSystem.String LiteralNullSystem.String LiteralUndefinedSystem.String LiteralNotANumber
>    Fatal error in Mono CIL Linker
>    Mono.Cecil.ResolutionException: Failed to resolve System.Web.AspNetHostingPermissionLevel
>      at Mono.Cecil.Mixin.CheckedResolve (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference self) [0x00000] in :0 
>      at Mono.Cecil.SignatureReader.ReadCustomAttributeEnum (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference enum_type) [0x00000] in :0 
>      at Mono.Cecil.SignatureReader.ReadCustomAttributeElementValue (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type) [0x00000] in :0 
>      at Mono.Cecil.SignatureReader.ReadCustomAttributeElement (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type) [0x00000] in :0 
>      at Mono.Cecil.SignatureReader.ReadCustomAttributeFixedArgument (Mono.Cecil.TypeReference type) [0x00000] in :0 
>      at Mono.Cecil.SignatureReader.ReadCustomAttributeNamedArgument (Mono.Collections.Generic.Collection`1& fields, Mono.Collections.Generic.Collection`1& properties) [0x00000] in :0 
>      at Mono.Cecil.SignatureReader.ReadCustomAttributeNamedArguments (UInt16 count, Mono.Collections.Generic.Collection`1& fields, Mono.Collections.Generic.Collection`1& properties) [0x00000] in :0 
>      at Mono.Cecil.SignatureReader.ReadSecurityAttribute () [0x00000] in :0 
>      at Mono.Cecil.MetadataReader.ReadSecurityDeclarationSignature (Mono.Cecil.SecurityDeclaration declaration) [0x00000] in :0 
>      at Mono.Cecil.SecurityDeclaration.b__2 (Mono.Cecil.SecurityDeclaration declaration, Mono.Cecil.MetadataReader reader) [0x00000] in :0 
>      at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Read[SecurityDeclaration,SecurityDeclaration] (Mono.Cecil.SecurityDeclaration item, System.Func`3 read) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>      at Mono.Cecil.SecurityDeclaration.Resolve () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>      at Mono.Cecil.SecurityDeclaration.get_SecurityAttributes () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>      at Mono.Cecil.ImmediateModuleReader.ReadSecurityDeclarations (ISecurityDeclarationProvider provider) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>      at Mono.Cecil.ImmediateModuleReader.ReadType (Mono.Cecil.TypeDefinition type) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
>      at Mono.Cecil.ImmediateModuleReader.ReadTypes (Mono.Collections.Generic.Collection`1 types) [0x00000] in :0 
>      at Mono.Cecil.ImmediateModuleReader.ReadModule (Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition module) [0x00000] in :0 
>      at Mono.Cecil.ModuleWriter.WriteModuleTo (Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition module, System.IO.Stream stream, Mono.Cecil.WriterParameters parameters) [0x00000] in :0 
>      at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Write (System.IO.Stream stream, Mono.Cecil.WriterParameters parameters) [0x00000] in :0 
>      at Mono.Cecil.ModuleDefinition.Write (System.String fileName, Mono.Cecil.WriterParameters parameters) [0x00000] in :0 
>      at Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition.Write (System.String fileName, Mono.Cecil.WriterParameters parameters) [0x00000] in :0 
>      at Mono.Linker.Steps.OutputStep.OutputAssembly (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x00000] in :0 
>      at Mono.Linker.Steps.OutputStep.ProcessAssembly (Mono.Cecil.AssemblyDefinition assembly) [0x00000] in :0 
>      at Mono.Linker.Steps.BaseStep.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00000] in :0 
>      at Mono.Linker.Pipeline.Process (Mono.Linker.LinkContext context) [0x00000] in :0 
>      at Mono.Linker.Driver.Run () [0x00000] in :0 
>      at Mono.Linker.Driver.RunDriver (Mono.Linker.Driver driver) [0x00000] in :0 
>    stderr:
>
> UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
>    UnityEditorInternal.Runner:RunManagedProgram(String, String, String, CompilerOutputParserBase) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:66)
>    UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper:RunAssemblyLinker(IEnumerable`1, String&, String&, String, String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:192)
>    UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper:StripAssembliesTo(String, String, String&, String&, String, String, IEnumerable`1) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:185)
>    UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper:Strip(String, String, String&, String&, String, String, IEnumerable`1) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:136)
>    UnityEditorInternal.AssemblyStripper:Strip(String[], String[], String, String, String&, String&, String, String, IEnumerable`1) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:121)
>    UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:RunAssemblyStripper(IEnumerable, String, String[], String[], String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:444)
>    UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:StripAssemblies(IEnumerable`1, String) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:417)
>    UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPBuilder:Run() (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:291)
>    UnityEditorInternal.IL2CPPUtils:RunIl2Cpp(String, String, IIl2CppPlatformProvider, Action`1, RuntimeClassRegistry) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/BuildPipeline/Il2Cpp/IL2CPPUtils.cs:211)
>    UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()

Error2:

> Error building Player: Exception: D:\Program Files (x86)\Unity\Editor\Data\Tools/UnusedByteCodeStripper2/UnusedBytecodeStripper2.exe did not run properly!

Error3:

> InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object
>    System.Collections.Stack.Peek () (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Collections/Stack.cs:321)
>    UnityEngine.GUILayoutUtility.EndLayoutGroup () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUILayoutUtility.cs:278)
>    UnityEngine.GUILayout.EndScrollView (Boolean handleScrollWheel) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/IMGUI/Managed/GUILayout.cs:427)
>    UnityEditor.EditorGUILayout.EndScrollView () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/EditorGUI.cs:6808)
>    UnityEditor.ListViewShared+ListViewElementsEnumerator.MoveNext () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/GUI/ListViewShared.cs:654)
>    UnityEditor.ConsoleWindow.OnGUI () (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Editor/Mono/ConsoleWindow.cs:407)
>    System.Reflection.MonoMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) (at /Users/builduser/buildslave/mono-runtime-and-classlibs/build/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:222)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the actual error message here is:

`Failed to resolve System.Web.AspNetHostingPermissionLevel`

This type is in the System.dll assembly (according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.aspnethostingpermissionlevel(v=vs.110).aspx)). Unity references the System.dll assembly, so it should be able to find this assembly. However, Unity can target different .NET profiles.

Look for the current profile setting by choosing File > Build Settings from the menu, then select the Player Settings button. You should see something like this in the inspector:

[image]

Make sure that you are using the ".NET 2.0" option here, not the ".NET 2.0 Subset" option. The type `System.Web.AspNetHostingPermissionLevel` does not exist in the .NET 2.0 Subset profile.

It is likely the case that some pre-built assembly in the project was built against the .NET 2.0 profile, so it is trying to use this type.

Comment: Thanks for you help. But I really use the ".NET 2.0",

Comment: I'm not sure then. Maybe the System.dll assembly cannot be found for some reason. You might be able to eliminate pre-built assembly one by one from the project until you find the culprit.

Comment: I have have solved the issue by creating link.xml in Assets floder。
I create a xml file named link.
the file like this:
<linker>
<assembly fullname="System">
   <namespace fullname="System.Web.AspNetHostingPermissionLevel" preserve="all"/>
</linker>